# Task :app:installDebug [EmulatorConsole]: Failed to start Emulator console for 5554 09:17:15

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run react-native on my Leapdroid emulator but when it gets to the point of installing the app I see this error.

> Task :app:installDebug
>   [EmulatorConsole]: Failed to start Emulator console for 5554
>   09:17:15 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
>   09:17:16 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   09:17:16 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'emulator-5554 - 4.4.4' for app:debug
>   09:17:16 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   09:17:16 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   09:17:16 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\medlib\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
>   <============-> 99% EXECUTING [36m 3s]
>   :app:installDebug
>   IDLE

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have occurred in `emulator`, not `Android studio`. Try changing the `AVD` setting to `"Use Host GPU."`