# react-native run-android stuck indefinitely at EXECUTING 97% app:installDebug

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, gradle

Firstly, an error appeared simultaneously in every React Native proyect in computer, this happened overnight.

```
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

Refence to the [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71771423/react-native-compilejava-task-current-target-is-1-8-and-compilekotlin-tas), solved it by chaging distributionUrl property in graddle-wrapper.properties, to version 7.4.2. and running `gradlew clean` afterwards

This solved the issue only on that proyect, so i don't know if it's the best solution. I can only think there must've been some sort of automatic update overnight (which would be absolute nonsense, because npm does not update anything unless told to).

Anyhow, on this particular proyect where I implemented the solution i'm getting this other problem (I can't even call it an error)

```
Task :app:installDebug
[EmulatorConsole]: Failed to start Emulator console for 5554
<============-> 97% EXECUTING [39m 14s]
> :app:installDebug
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
```

after a couple seconds into the "EXECUTING" phase, I get this error message on top of the dialog stating:

```
Task :app:installDebug
[EmulatorConsole]: Failed to start Emulator console for 5554
```

The process is not killed by this 'error' so i don't know if it's a warning or an actual error.

The terminal can be up to 18hrs stuck like this (the timer just keeps on going) so i'm certain this is some sort of infinite loop, or a process without a timeout.

I've tried several different stackOverflow solutions to problems that were very similar to mine, but apparently not the same. Both for [app:installDebug FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500205/react-native-appinstalldebug-failed) and for [EmulatorConsole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102968/task-appinstalldebug-emulatorconsole-failed-to-start-emulator-console-for-5), but the solution doesn't seem to be applicable to my case (that or i just dont understand it)

This is my third day trying to solve this issue. Plase help!!!! and thanks in advance

Comment: It got solved by itself, 3 days passed. I tried running it again this morning and everything was working fine.